# Android creating listview not working

Tags: java, android, listview

I am a newbie to Android.I am creating a simple app which shows a list of state names in listview and when I click on any of the textview, the capital of the state should be in the textview. Here is the code:

The problem is this that it is not running, whenever I try to run this: "application closed unexpectedly" message appears. Please help me where I am doing wrong.

**Here is my XML**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:id="@+id/txtv1"
    />
<ListView
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/l"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Here is my activity code**

```
`import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class LVjavaActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener, OnItemSelectedListener{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    TextView t;
    ListView lv;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
       lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.l);
       t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtv1);

       ArrayList<String> state=new ArrayList<String>();
       state.add("Andhra Pradesh");
       state.add("Bihar");
       state.add("Goa");
       state.add("Orrisa");
       state.add("Punjab");
       ArrayAdapter <String> adp=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.mytxtv, state);
       lv.setAdapter(adp);
       lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
       lv.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); 

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(arg2){
        case 0:
            t.setText("Hyderabad");
        break;
        case 1:
            t.setText("Patna");
        break;
        case 2:
            t.setText("Panaji");
        break;
        case 3:
            t.setText("Bhuvaneshwar");
        break;
        case 4:
            t.setText("Chandigarh");
            break;
        }

    }
}`
```

Here is the Logcat

```
11-06 11:56:08.086: ERROR/ArrayAdapter(1169): You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
11-06 11:56:08.116: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1169): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 11:56:08.116: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1169): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
11-06 11:56:08.116: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:347)
11-06 11:56:08.116: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
11-06 11:56:08.116: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
11-06 11:56:08.116: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1216)
11-06 11:56:08.116: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1127)
11-06 11:56:08.116: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-06 11:56:08.116: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
11-06 11:56:08.116: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
11-06 11:56:08.116: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
11-06 11:56:08.116: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
11-06 11:56:08.116: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-06 11:56:08.116: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
11-06 11:56:08.116: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
11-06 11:56:08.116: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-06 11:56:08.116: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
11-06 11:56:08.116: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
11-06 11:56:08.116: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-06 11:56:08.116: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
11-06 11:56:08.116: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
11-06 11:56:08.116: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-06 11:56:08.116: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:839)
11-06 11:56:08.116: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
11-06 11:56:08.116: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-06 11:56:08.116: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-06 11:56:08.116: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-06 11:56:08.116: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-06 11:56:08.116: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-06 11:56:08.116: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-06 11:56:08.116: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-06 11:56:08.116: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-06 11:56:08.116: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1169): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
11-06 11:56:08.116: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:340)
11-06 11:56:08.116: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1169):     ... 29 more
11-06 13:26:25.855: ERROR/ArrayAdapter(3397): You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
11-06 13:26:25.895: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3397): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 13:26:25.895: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3397): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
11-06 13:26:25.895: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3397):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:347)
11-06 13:26:25.895: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3397):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
11-06 13:26:25.895: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3397):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
11-06 13:26:25.895: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3397):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1216)
11-06 13:26:25.895: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3397):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1127)
11-06 13:26:25.895: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3397):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-06 13:26:25.895: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3397):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
11-06 13:26:25.895: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3397):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
11-06 13:26:25.895: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3397):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
11-06 13:26:25.895: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3397):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
11-06 13:26:25.895: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3397):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-06 13:26:25.895: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3397):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
11-06 13:26:25.895: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3397):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
11-06 13:26:25.895: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3397):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-06 13:26:25.895: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3397):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
11-06 13:26:25.895: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3397):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
11-06 13:26:25.895: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3397):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-06 13:26:25.895: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3397):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
11-06 13:26:25.895: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3397):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
11-06 13:26:25.895: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3397):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-06 13:26:25.895: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3397):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:839)
11-06 13:26:25.895: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3397):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
11-06 13:26:25.895: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3397):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-06 13:26:25.895: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3397):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-06 13:26:25.895: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3397):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-06 13:26:25.895: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3397):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-06 13:26:25.895: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3397):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-06 13:26:25.895: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3397):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-06 13:26:25.895: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3397):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-06 13:26:25.895: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3397):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-06 13:26:25.895: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3397): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
11-06 13:26:25.895: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3397):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:340)
11-06 13:26:25.895: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3397):     ... 29 more
```

Comment: error log plzzz

Comment: "application closed unexpectedly" means your app crashed . Check the errror logs please.

Comment: Post the logcat of your error. "application closed unexpectedly" happens at different way. Only log can help others to identify what you really need.

Comment: solved this yet?

Answer (score 3):

change

```
lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.l);
t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtv1);
```

To

```
lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv1);
t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
```

You bind wrong id

Comment: Yes you right with the id. but op how didn't get the bind error in IDE to resolve the issues.If he bind it incorrectly he should get error in coding.

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH possible of cache cleaning problem or you have that's id on another layout

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH  if ans helped you then you can also accept it as right answer happy coding...!!

Comment: i can't accept, only original poster(op) should accept answer.

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH opps..!! it's my mistake i think you are a poster..